# how to add the IF NOT EXISTS clause or REFRESH clause in databricks python

Tags: python, azure-databricks

Cannot create table or view  `abc` because it already exists.
Choose a different name, drop or replace the existing object, add the IF NOT EXISTS clause to tolerate pre-existing objects, or add the OR REFRESH clause to refresh the existing streaming table. SQLSTATE: 42P07

```
     sdf_ext = spark.sql (
      sql_code_ext
       )
     sdf_ext.write.saveAsTable("abc")
```

Comment: you can save the table using the append mode

Comment: The "if not exists" is relevant to creating the table with an SQL command, and the "refresh" option is relevant to streaming. In your Python code, you need to add .mode("overwrite") or .mode("append") like @DileeprajnarayanThumula said.

Comment: thank you Chen Hirsh, I added .mode("overwrite") and it works

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that a table or view with the name "**abc**" already exists.

I have tried below as an example:

```
sql_code_ext = "SELECT * FROM v1"
sdf_ext = spark.sql(sql_code_ext)
if spark.catalog.tableExists("N1"):
    print("Table N1 already exists, skipping saving or save it in append mode")
else:
    sdf_ext.write.saveAsTable("N1")
    print("Table N1 saved.")
```

In Python there is no direct way to use `IF NOT EXISTS` like you use in sql.

In such situations you use .mode("append") to add the data to the table or use above code to check condition.

Result:

```
%sql
Select * from N1
```

```
name    age
Jane    30
John    25
Bob     35
```

Yes you can use the .mode("overwrite") The overwrite mode is used to overwrite the existing file

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys, and I added .mode("overwrite") as display below, because i may run/test new code multiple times.

```
sdf_ext = spark.sql (sql_code_ext)
 sdf_ext.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("abc")
```

thanks again!